# Haproxy configuration for solr read only access

Tags: solr, haproxy

I have to use HAProxy for load balancing for Apache Solr. As I know any one can send any type of request to solr. What should be the rule to allow client read only access to solr via haproxy. Before this I was using [node.js](https://github.com/dergachev/solr-security-proxy) solr proxy that server this purpose successfully.

Comment: A complete tutorial about how to setup Haproxy with Solr: https://manios.org/2017/11/15/use-haproxy-and-docker-for-solr-load-balancing